# Is it possible create one subscription across multiple apps?

Tags: android, android-billing, play-billing-library

I have two versions of my app:

1. With ads
2. Without ads.

And I have subscriptions in my app. I want to share one subscription across these apps. For example such a scenario:

The user buys a subscription in the app with ads and later he buys app without ads. I want to share the subscription in the first app to the second. Is it possible with the standard google billing library?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @DevanshiModha I found that this is not possible. If You should share subscriptions across multiple apps you should create your own authorization system and connect subscriptions to users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this is not possible. If You should share subscriptions across multiple apps you should create your own authorization system and connect subscriptions to users.